# get Date and time according to specified another time and its timezone [in flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, timezone

i am developing an app in which i need to get my current date and time according to specified another time and its timezone

example -

- I have a timezone (ex -"asia/bangkok") and its time as 2020-11-20 10:00 AM
- And i want a new TIME according to this specified time and with my TIMEZONE

so if in asia/bangkok the time is 2020-11-20 10:00 AM ,then i want to find a TIME according to my current timezone which is "asia/kalkata" !

if anyone understood this question then kindly help me!

Comment: [`package:timezone`](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) might be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is easily doable just using built-in methods.

There is however a package that helps out with that type of conversions.

Have a look at the Instant package:
https://pub.dev/packages/instant

The documentation describing your conversion is available at:
https://akushwarrior2.gitbook.io/instant/adv-use#converting-between-timezones